# How to use Oracle EF Core using Row version

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

I have migrated a database layer from NHibernate to Oracle EF Core 6.x
The Oracle database is the same.

One of the tables has an integer version column.

How can I get EF to increment the value? Have tried incrementing it on save but this gives me a concurrency exception.

Mapping of the column:

```
b.Property(x => x.Version).HasColumnName("VERSION").IsRowVersion();
```

I have also tried a timestamp but not sure what datatype to use in C# and Oracle.
Would also prefer to keep the integer version column. So I can avoid a datamigration.

Comment: A `rowversion` column should be updated by the database, not the client. It's used in optimistic concurrency to detect changes to the underlying data made by another connection. Does the table have a trigger that updates the column perhaps? How was it updated with NHibernate?

Comment: NHibernate did the update of the version column
http://www.canertosuner.com/post/optimisticlock-using-fluent-nhibernate1

Comment: That would be a hack to avoid writing triggers. If a row was updated outside NHibernate, your application would have no way to know and would end up overwriting any changes. Are you **absolutely sure** the column is updated by the *client* ?

Comment: NHibernate update the column as part of the update

Comment: From my perspective, the developer should be able to choose which way to go. We use a version column which needs to be updated by the client application. In case, the update fails because a row with some version already exists, the client knows that somebody else already updated the row and needs to get the latest version first.